# Multiple columns sum difference in a single formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Working a spreadsheet timecard of sorts in excel where i have column A is the charge code, column B is clock-in time, and column C is clock out time.

I'd like to then produce a table where:

Column 1 has the various labor codes (i used unique filter)
Column 2 has the sum of the hours worked under each code.

So, the result should look like this:

[image]

B13 formula i'm using is:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A3:A10,A3:A10<>""))
```

`C13:C16`..etc can be in either `HH:MM` or decimal hour notation. doesn't matter to me.

I'd like to do this avoiding helper columns and VBA

Thank you for your help!

I've tried numerous mixtures of sum, sumif, match, filter and it isnt working out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something along the lines using <kbd>MAP( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B10`

```
=LET(
  _code,A3:A8,
  _timeIn,B3:B8,
  _timeOut,C3:C8,
  _uCode,UNIQUE(_code),
  VSTACK({"CODE","Hours"},HSTACK(_uCode,
  MAP(_uCode,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(_code=x)*(_timeOut-_timeIn))))))
)
```

---

Or, without using any <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper functions

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B10`

```
=LET(
 _code,A3:A8,
 _timeIn,B3:B8,
 _timeOut,C3:C8,
 _uCode,UNIQUE(_code),
 VSTACK({"CODE","Hours"},
 HSTACK(_uCode,
 MMULT(N(_uCode=TOROW(_code)),(_timeOut-_timeIn)))))
```

---

Or, more easier way using <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd> <kbd>UNIQUE( )</kbd> <kbd>HSTACK( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B10`

```
=VSTACK({"CODE","Hours"},
 UNIQUE(HSTACK(A3:A8,
 MMULT(N(A3:A8=TOROW(A3:A8)),(C3:C8-B3:B8)))))
```

---

**Note:** Format the cells for `Hours` Column as `[h]:mm;@`

---